# Difference between Riemann sums and Riemann integrals

Tags: integration

I have a question that says "Calculate the following Riemann integrals". I know about Riemann sums. Is there any difference between Riemann sums and Riemann integrals?

Comment: The Riemann integral is a limit of Riemann sums.

Comment: so would I just use the same method as I would with a normal Riemann sum question?

Answer (score 1):

The Riemann integral is that integral defined in terms of limits of Riemann sums (as opposed to, e.g., the Lebesgue integral).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read the definition of the Riemann integral carefully. You will very rarely find a case where a Riemann integral can be calculated by using a sum.